# SQLite: Total Column value and then compare to input

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

In my test program, users input a total time that they want a playlist to be, and it then generates a playlist that is no longer then the time given. **However, I am having a few issues with this, as I cannot figure out how to TOTAL the Length of songs in the playlist, and then make sure that the query is no longer then the time given.** Please could someone help me?
This is my code:

`c.execute ('SELECT (TOTAL(Length) AS TotalSongLength, "Song Name", "Artist", "Genre", "Album", "Year") FROM Songs WHERE TotalSongLength <= "{0}"'.format(TotalSongLengthInput))`

All that happens before the code is a user inputs a time limit. In the Table, songs are stored into `MM:SS` format, and their input is automatically converted to that format. I am *just* struggling with the above question ^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following may suit :-

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN seconds > 0 AND seconds < 300 
        THEN 'Playlist OK' 
        ELSE 'Playlist too long or not long enough' 
    END AS result
FROM 
    (SELECT sum((substr(length,1,2) * 60) + substr(length,4,2)) as seconds 
    FROM songs);
```

- Where **300** is the total time allowed.

### Testing

This was tested using:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS songs;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs ("Song Name" TEXT,"Artist" TEXT, "Genre" TEXT, "Album" TEXT, "Year", length TEXT);
INSERT INTO songs VALUES ('My Song','Fred','Rock','Fred Rocks','1974', '03:11');
INSERT INTO songs VALUES ('Another Song','Bert','Pop','Bert sings','2010', '02:59');
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN seconds > 0 AND seconds < 300 THEN 'Playlist OK' ELSE 'Playlist too long or not long enough' END AS result

FROM (SELECT sum((substr(length,1,2) * 60) + substr(length,4,2)) as seconds FROM songs)
```

and then :-

- a) commenting out all inserts(songs),
- b) commenting out first song,
- c) commenting out second song and
- d) not commenting out any songs

#### testing Results

- a) Playlist too long or not long enough
- b) Playlist OK
- c) Playlist OK
- d) Playlist too long or not long enough

If you wanted the time in seconds as well then :-

```
SELECT seconds,
    CASE 
        WHEN seconds > 0 AND seconds < 300 
        THEN 'Playlist OK' 
        ELSE 'Playlist too long or not long enough' 
    END AS result
FROM 
    (SELECT sum((substr(length,1,2) * 60) + substr(length,4,2)) as seconds FROM songs);
```

- Note if no rows then seconds would be null rather than 0.

#### Re Comment :-

> it's not quite what I am looking for. Instead of saying if the
>   playlist is below a certain time or whatever. I want it to display all
>   the songs that can add together, WITHOUT going over the User Input

I believe the following will do that (1000 on the last line being the time limit) :-

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT SUM(a.seconds) AS summed, 
        b."Song Name", 
        b."Artist", 
        b."Genre", 
        b."Album", 
        b."Year", 
        b.length, 
        b.seconds 
    FROM  (
        SELECT *,
            (substr(length,1,2) * 60) + substr(length,4,2) AS seconds 
        FROM songs ORDER BY length) AS a,
    (
        SELECT *,
            (substr(length,1,2) * 60) + substr(length,4,2) AS seconds 
        FROM songs ORDER BY length) AS b 
    WHERE b."Song Name" <= a."Song Name"
    GROUP BY b."Song Name" ORDER BY summed
) 
WHERE summed <= 1000
```

Based upon the table :-

[image]

Running the above results in :-

Limit = 1000 :-

[image]

Limit = 10000 :-

[image]

Limit = 600 :-

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time to write this all out and test it for me. The code DOES work, however, it's not quite what I am looking for. Instead of saying if the playlist is below a certain time or whatever. I want it to display all the songs that can add together, WITHOUT going over the User Input.

Comment: @JamesSmith edited the answer with what might be a solution

Comment: P.S This isn't the most efficient solution and can be quite resource hungry as the rows to process is the number of rows in the table * the number of rows in the table.

Comment: Okay, that works perfectly! Thank you so much for taking the time to do this and help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sum  and group  by

and for filter the result you should use having (for aggregated  result) and not where

```
 SELECT sum(Length) AS TotalSongLength, "Song Name", "Artist", "Genre", "Album", "Year" 
 FROM Songs 
 GROUP BY "Song Name", "Artist", "Genre", "Album", "Year" 
 HAVING TotalSongLength <= "{0}"'
```

Comment: Okay, this would work great, however, as the format of the songs are stored as `MM:SS` It's not working.
Is there a way to get it to convert the `MM:SS` to Seconds, and then make the SUM(Length[In Seconds]) <= {0}?

Comment: Hey again, I took what @Jeremy said, and instead converted each song into seconds (as a new column: `LengthSeconds`), so in theory, you're code *should* work, however, it is still giving me way over 600 seconds (10 minutes) of songs. :/

Answer (score 0):

Cant reply to comments yet, but scaisEdge gives you the answer to what you need

Datatype on the table is going to force you to do some conversions to seconds for everything you look at then, something like this:

```
 SELECT 
       SongName
     , strftime('%MM', Length) * 60 + strftime('%SS',Length) AS TotalSeconds
     , Length
 FROM Songs 
 GROUP BY SongName, Length
 HAVING TotalSeconds <= "{0}"
```

Then you'd have to parse the user input into seconds as well to compare to TotalSeconds

Comment: Hi, please read the comment that I sent to @scaisEdge 's comment.